# orbit controller in three.js not working on the static scene with obj model loaded

Tags: typescript, three.js

in my scene, orbit controller is not working and this is my code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls'
import { MTLLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/MTLLoader'
import { OBJLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader'
import { CSS2DRenderer, CSS2DObject } from 'three/examples/jsm/renderers/CSS2DRenderer'
// import { TWEEN } from 'https://unpkg.com/three@0.139.0/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module.min.js'


function addCamera() {
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        90,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
    )
    camera.position.set(15, 5, 10)
    return camera
}

function addLight(scene: THREE.Scene) {
    const dirLight_right_near = new THREE.DirectionalLight()
    dirLight_right_near.position.set(30, 50, 40)
    scene.add(dirLight_right_near)

    const dirLight_left_far = new THREE.DirectionalLight()
    dirLight_left_far.position.set(-30, 50, -40)
    scene.add(dirLight_left_far)

    return scene
}

let scene = new THREE.Scene()
let camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera
let raycaster: THREE.Raycaster

let sceneObject = new Array()
scene = addLight(scene)
camera = addCamera()
raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster()

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const element = document.createElement('div') as HTMLElement
const labelRenderer = new CSS2DRenderer()
labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, innerHeight)
labelRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute'
labelRenderer.domElement.style.top = '0px'
document.body.appendChild(labelRenderer.domElement)

const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement) // (, html element used for event listener)
controls.target.set(10.0, 0.0, 0.0)
console.log(controls)

const objLoader = new OBJLoader()
new MTLLoader().setPath('models/').load('house_water.mtl', function (materials) {
    materials.preload()
    console.log('hi')
    objLoader
        .setMaterials(materials)
        .setPath('models/')
        .load('house_water.obj', function (object) {
            object.scale.set(0.01, 0.01, 0.01)
            scene.add(object)
            // object.traverse(function (child) {
            //     if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
            //         scene.add(child)
            //     }
            // })
        })
})

window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize)

function onWindowResize() {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix()
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    labelRenderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
    render()
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
    controls.update()

    // console.log(camera.position)
    render()
}

function render() {
    labelRenderer.render(scene, camera)
    renderer.render(scene, camera)
}
animate()
```

can anyone please help me on this !!

Comment: Not working as in...?
Please consider preparing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @lifetimeLearner007 's answer should fix your problem. Moreover, in your addCamera function you only instantiated the camera in memory but you never actually added it to the scene, even if you pass the camera as a parameter to the orbit controls and to the renderer, the renderer will only render 1 image of the scene. Hence, adding the camera to the scene fixes your problem

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding the camera to the scene. This should fix the issue. Hope it helps!

```
...
camera = addCamera();
scene.add(camera);
...
```